# Running a linux command from python

Tags: python, linux

I need to run this linux command from python and assign the output to a variable.

```
ps -ef | grep rtptransmit | grep -v grep
```

I've tried using pythons commands library to do this.

```
import commands
a = commands.getoutput('ps -ef | grep rtptransmit | grep -v grep')
```

But a gets the end of cut off. The output I get is:

```
'nvr      20714 20711  0 10:39 ?        00:00:00 /opt/americandynamics/venvr/bin/rtptransmit setup_req db=media  camera=6  stream=video  substream=1  client_a'
```

but the expected output is:

```
nvr      20714 20711  0 10:39 ?        00:00:00 /opt/americandynamics/venvr/bin/rtptransmit setup_req db=media  camera=6  stream=video  substream=1  client_address=192.168.200.179  client_rtp_port=6970  override_lockout=1  clienttype=1
```

Does anyone know how to stop the output from getting cut off or can anyone suggest another method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ps` apparently limits its output to fit into the presumed width of the terminal.  You can override this width with the `$COLUMNS` environment variable or with the `--columns` option to `ps`.

The `commands` module is deprecated.  Use `subprocess` to get the output of `ps -ef` and filter the output in Python.  Do not use `shell=True` as suggested by other answers, it is simply superfluous in this case:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-ef', '--columns', '1000'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
for line in output.splitlines():
    if 'rtptransmit' in line:
        print(line)
```

You may also want to take a look the `pgrep` command by which you can directly search for specific processes.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use `subprocess` for running an external command. For your case, you can do something like the following

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('ps -ef | grep rtptransmit | grep -v grep', shell=True,
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

The output will be in `out` variable.

Comment: The `shell` is needed if you want to use pipe in the command. About the `grep`, I actually just copied and pasted the command from the question. That second `grep` I suspect is there because sometimes the `grep` command that we execute also appears to be grep-ed and therefore need to be removed. This actually can be avoided using `grep [r]tptransmit`

Comment: I know that `shell=True` is required to use a pipe in the command, and that the second `grep` is to remove the first `grep` command from the filtered process list.  But both, the pipe and `grep` are superfluous in this case.

Comment: @lunaryorn it is worse. The Python code produces a truncated output in my environment: it seems if `$COLUMNS` is set implicitly then `ps` ignores it e.g., the output (in the shell) is longer than `shutil.get_terminal_size()` and `os.environ['COLUMNS']` raises KeyError but `echo $COLUMNS` corresponds to `shutil.get_terminal_size()`.

Answer (score 5):

`commands` is deprecated, you should not use it. Use `subprocess` instead

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output('ps -ef | grep rtptransmit | grep -v grep', shell=True)
```

Comment: @lunaryorn: question is how to run that command in Python, not how to grep that in Python.

Comment: Actually the question is how to avoid truncation of the `ps` output.  But that doesn't contradict my point…

Comment: @lunaryorn: also, without `shell=True` shell pipes won't work, so you wrong on that one too.

Comment: So what? The point is that you don't need shell pipes in this case…

Comment: There are many ways to get the output of `ps`, from a bad one to a good one. However the output will get truncated if the `ps`column width is not set and this is the point of the question and answer. So, arguing that using shell and pipes is not necessary is just silly because it's not the point.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

a = os.system("cat /var/log/syslog")

print a


from subprocess import call

b = call("ls -l", shell=True)

print b


import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.check_output('ps -ef | grep kernel', shell=True)

print cmd
```

Any of the above script will work for you :-)

Answer (score -1):

```sh
nano test.py
```

```py
import os
a = os.system('ps -ef | grep rtptransmit | grep -v grep')
print(a)
```

```sh
python test.py
```

```sh
python3 test.py
```

[Run python file using both python and python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zijk9.png)

[Run python script using python and python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PwW8.png)

Comment: Could you please add more information on how this solution solves the issue?

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.